# Android ListAdapter with onClickListner using Array HashMap

Tags: android, listview, hashmap

I'm looking at creating a `ListView` using a `HashMap` array. But I have been unable to find any examples that use a `HashMap` array, I understand the concepts of using `ListViews` but I can't seem to incorporate it using a `HashMap` array. Does anyone know of any examples that they could point me to please, there are a couple of examples on SO where people use just a `HashMap` but none with type array.

Many thanks for your help this has been driving me nuts for two weeks off and on.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.deals);

    ds = new DealsSQL(DealsUI.this);
    dm = new DealsManage(DealsUI.this);

    //new LoadDeals().execute();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> inboxList new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(new HashMapAdapter(inboxList));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        });
}

public class HashMapAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private String[] mKeys;
    public HashMapAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> inboxList){
        mData  = inboxList;
        mKeys = mData.keySet().toArray(new String[inboxList.size()]);

    }


    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }


    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(mKeys[position]);
    }


    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }


    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String key = mKeys[pos];
        String Value = getItem(pos).toString();

        //do your view stuff here

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing now is retrieving a HashMap on every listitem. What I assume (from your code) you want to do is, in every row of your `ListView`, fetch & display the contents of your `HashMap<String,String>`. That said, here is an example.

Creating a `ListView` with an `ArrayList` of `HashMap<?,?>` is no different from any other `ArrayList`. In your `getView(...)`-method, fetch the current item using `int pos` and the `getItem(int pos)` method. Then, construct your views as you normally would.

For more info on the ViewHolder pattern (and convertView), check http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_hoder.

Example:

```
...

/**
 * Return the HashMap that is stored in your ArrayList at position, instead
 * of just the value.
 */
public HashMap<String, String> getItem(int position) {
    return mData.get(position);
}

...

public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    HashMap<String, String> item = getItem(pos);
    ViewHolder holder;        

    if(convertView == null) {
        // ConvertView is re-used by ListView. That means we don't have to re-inflate
        // it on every row. Instead, if convertView is already set we just reuse it.
        // To prevent having to call .findViewById( id ) every time, we use the pattern
        // called the `ViewHolder`-pattern.
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textview1 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = convertView.getTag();
    }

    // now, we have both a populated convertView and a reference to it's individual subviews
    // in the form of holder.

    // manipulate the views in your listitem here
    // I assume you want to display the contents of the HashMap<String,String> here
    // so convert the HashMap to something iterable, like EntrySet
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            // notice how we set the TextView attributes by accessing holder.textview1
            holder.textview1.setText( key + " => " + value + "\n");
    }


    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textview1;
}
```

.

### NOTE:

If you just want to display a listitem for each of your HashMap entries, I think your best best is to convert it to an array using `hashmap.entrySet().toArray()` and feed that array to your HashMapAdapter in the constructor, which will give you an array of `Map.Entry` as your `mDataset`. In your `getView(...)`-method, instead of looping through your data-item, you'd then just use `item.getKey()` and `item.getValue()`. Also, your `getItem(position)`-method would have to return type `Map.Entry` instead of `HashMap<String, String>`.